# Codeigniter chrone not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have added the following code in my codeigniter page like to call a function `test_cron` in  `scheduler` controller for setting a crone.But it always return the html of my `default_controller`

```
$application_folder = 'application';
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = '/scheduler/test_cron';
$_GET = '/scheduler/test_cron'; // Required for some installations  

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/scheduler/test_cron';
```

Please help me

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your want to run a codeigniter function by cronjob. Correct way to do this is:

```
pahto_codeigniter/index.php scheduler test_cron
```

Codeingiter documention refference: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html